# 64GB CF Card exFat Format in D300?

Tags: file-format, nikon-d300

I just bought a Sandisk 64GB CF card to use in a Nikon D300. Display says card is full. I reformatted the card in my PC, no luck. I formatted the card in my camera, same thing. Card appears to format properly but camera still displays "Full" message. Is the exFat file system incompatible with a D300?

Comment: Just a FYI, I've been bitten similarly before.  Since then, I've *always* gone by what's officially supported (e.g.: https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/ni/NI_article?articleNo=000002637&configured=1&lang=en_US )

Answer (score 1):

Some folks have reported similar issues with D700's and fixed by going into the shooting menu, and creating a new active folder, then formatting the card.

See 9th response in this [forum thread](http://www.naturelyrics.com/blog/creative-artistic-nature-photography/fatal-nikon-d700-firmware-bug/#comment-22303)

Answer (score 1):

The **Nikon D300 does not support 64GB cards** this is because the `exfat` format required to address a volume of that size is not implemented in any firmware version for this body.

The *D300s* can support `exfat` with the appropriate firmware update but is a different camera, the firmware cannot be applied to the D300.

Comment: Does anyone know if D300 having some hardware limitation that constraint this or just firmware? If just firmware we can 'hope' that eventually a firmware update will come out to allow 64gb CF? (Or Nikon just think D300 development is not worthwhile anymore seeing that it is 'ancient'...)

Comment: exFAT is NOT required for 64GiB. FAT32 is fine for up to 2TiB with smallest sector size. CF protocol if implemented correctly does not limit the card size at all, many very old laptops with CF slots now accept 32GB+ cards without problems.

Comment: Actually it is, because the use of nonstandard sizes have implementation issues that can mean data loss, plus standards-wise the limit was raised above 32gb with the SDHC to SDXC cards which require the use of exfat so support would be necessary.  Certainly D300 firmware would have physical limits addressing such a volume and are likely to have problems.

Comment: It's a firmware limitation, but you aren't going to see a firmware update, not even nikonhackers have one in the works.  Manufacturers rarely if ever add features through firmware updates and certainly won't be adding them to a dslr of that vintage.

Comment: By force of habit, having been bitten before, I *always* check the tech specs before buying.  8GB is reported as the highest supported (YMMV beyond that?): 
https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/ni/NI_article?articleNo=000002637&configured=1&lang=en_US

Answer (score 0):

The D300s 1.01 supposedly had a software update that allowed it to use cards up to 64GB. I'm not sure whether or not the update was also available for the D300.

Many users have reported problems with using larger size cards. A good way to solve the problem is generally to format the card in the camera. Or perform a Low-Level format which will reset the card architecture.

It seems generally as a rule of thumb though that you don't use large cards in the D300/D300s.

Have a look at this forum post: http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3237997
It Iooks like according to SanDisk that the D300 is incompatible with 64GB cards: http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3684/~/nikon-d300s,-d700,-d3,-d3x-firmware-updates-for-64gb-compactflash

Answer (score 0):

So I have been able to get my D300 to "work" with a 128G CF disk by creating a 32G primary partition on the drive and formatting that with fat32. I did try formatting the entire drive in fat32 at 128G and 64G but the camera reads that it is full so camera is only able to read 32G FAT32 max.

I then made a NFTS partition on the rest of the disk to backup pictures manually on a computer with a CF card reader.

Of note however is do not try and format the disk with the camera. It will format the FAT32 partition up to max size, not the allocated size thus erasing the secondary NFTS partition on the disk and making the primary partition too large for the camera to use.

To make a 32G partition use disk management built into windows. Delete any volumes on the drive. Create a new primary partition and make it max 32,768mb which is binary for 32G. Format the drive in FAT32, not NTFS or exFAT. Then on the rest of drive you can create another partition with the rest of the drive and format it however you like

Comment: I apologize. I have a D300 not the 300S. The S I read with latest firmware can read exFAT.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Joseph's answer works. I bought a 64gb card for my D300 right before a trip, not realizing that 32gb was the max. In Windows, you may have to logon as admin to get access to Disk Management. On Windows 10/11, right-click Start to find Disk Management. I didn't make a partition; instead, I used right-click on the card and Shrink Volume to drop it down to 32gb. I went a little less at 31.5 GB. Format as FAT32 and good to go!

Comment: That answer has already been given.